# Reload /etc/profile in ksh shell

Tags: ksh, aix

I have updated /etc/profile on an AIX host and would like to reload in the same session without logging off.

Any idea how can we do it? I tried `source /etc/profile`, but it doesn't work in ksh (it does work in bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting the message "`/usr/bin/ksh: source:  not found`", you're probably using an older ksh shell that doesn't have the `source` command.  The way to source a file in with your older ksh shell is (as [Lorinczy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141064/lorinczy-zsigmond) commented):

```
. /etc/profile
```